# How can I centralize Gitlab CI Deployment / Environments information when a deploy job is initiated from a fork of the repository?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Each developer on our team forks the production repository, then opens MRs from their fork to merge into the master branch of the production one.

We have a fixed number of test environments which are shared by all developers. Eventually we hope to move to ephemeral environments for each MR but at the moment this is not possible.

We utilize the Environments / Deployments functionality of Gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/ and the production repository is the central location where we see what is deployed to each environment.

The problem is that when a developer opens a MR they frequently choose to manually deploy to one of our shared test environments. But since the pipeline for their branch runs in their fork it records the Environment / Deploy information there rather than in production. This makes it impossible for us to know who deployed what to each test environment as that information is recorded in random developer forks rather than in the centralized location.

We only deploy to production hosts from the production repository (it is disabled in developer forks) so that information is centralized and up to date. But it is a headache for developers to determine who has deployed something to one of the shared test environments and they frequently overwrite each others' changes by accident.

Is there any way for us to allow test deploys from developer branches, but centralize the information about what is deployed in each environment in the production repository?

Comment: Trigger the pipeline job in the production repository rather than run it in the fork? You can use the API to trigger the job.